# Django - 'elif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, django, web-development-server

I am developing a simple Django app. Is the piece of code below even valid?
My code :

```
{% if request.session.role is "Manager" %}
{% extends 'manager_base_nav.html' %}
{% elif request.session.role is "Agent" %}
{% extends 'agent_base_nav.html' %}
{% else %}
{% extends 'customer_base_nav.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: No, `extends` is always the top tag, and does not allow if-then-else logic.

Comment: Is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: make different templates that each extend a different base template, and let the view decide what template to render?

Comment: An alternative is to define *one* base template, and work with a parameter to render only specific parts of that base template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to put extends at top and if you want to use if or else in your app you can do it by definding a variable inside views.py

```
if request.session.role is "Manager":
    ex_template = 'manager_base_nav.html'
elif request.session.role is "Agent":
    ex_template = 'agent_base_nav.html' %}
else:
    ex_template = 'customer_base_nav.html'
```

and on your html file you have to do this

```
{% extends ex_template %}
```

Answer (score 0):

No this is not valid. As the [documentation on template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) says:

> If you use `{% extends %}` in a template, it must be the **first template tag** in that template. Template inheritance won’t work, otherwise.

You thus should work with different templates that each inherit from a different base template, and let the view logic decide what template to use.

Answer (score 0):

`{% extends %}` should be the first tag in the template.

You do what you want in `views.py` , something like this:

```
if request.user.role == manager:
       render something
else:
       render something else
```